# Not able to alter Organization-Wide Defaults (OWD) via Apex

Tags: apex, custom-object, soap-api, metadata-api, owd

I am trying to alter Organization-Wide Defaults (OWD) via apex using  https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi (Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API) tool.

I can create custom object with attribute 'sharingModel' set to 'Read' and it works fine. But when I try to update 'sharingModel' set to 'ReadWrite', it does not update to 'ReadWrite'. However, there is no error thrown and all other fields are updated except 'sharingModel'. Any help would be helpful.

Thanks

**Adding code:**
Code used from MetadataServiceExamples class.

This is when creating an object with sharingModel as "ReadWrite"

```
public static void createObject() { 
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.CustomObject customObject = new MetadataService.CustomObject();
    customObject.fullName = 'Test__c';
    customObject.label = 'Test'; 
    customObject.pluralLabel = 'Tests';
    customObject.nameField = new MetadataService.CustomField(); 
    customObject.nameField.type_x = 'Text'; 
    customObject.nameField.label = 'Test Record'; 
    customObject.deploymentStatus = 'Deployed'; 
    customObject.sharingModel = 'ReadWrite'; 
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customObject });
    handleSaveResults(results[0]); 
}
```

This is when updating the same object with sharingModel as "Private"

```
public static void upsertObject() { 
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService(); 
    MetadataService.CustomObject customObject = new MetadataService.CustomObject(); 
    customObject.fullName = 'Test__c'; 
    customObject.label = 'Test'; 
    customObject.pluralLabel = 'Tests Upsert'; 
    customObject.nameField = new MetadataService.CustomField(); 
    customObject.nameField.type_x = 'Text'; 
    customObject.nameField.label = 'Test Record Upsert'; 
    customObject.deploymentStatus = 'Deployed'; 
    customObject.sharingModel = 'Private'; 
    List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results = service.upsertMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customObject }); 
    handleUpsertResults(results[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Update

See Known Issue: [sharingModel does not update through Metadata API CRUD-based calls](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=sharingmodel-does-not-update-through-metadata-api-crud-based-calls&Id=a1p3A0000018CP2) (W-4865521 )

> **Summary**
>   sharingModel does not update through Metadata API CRUD-based calls
>
> API call finishes with success = true but the sharingModel for the object is not updated

One workaround that has so far come out of support case 18656360 is that you can change the sharingModel using a [`deploy()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) API call with a package zip file.

---

One possibility, check the API version of the Metadata API you are using.

From the documentation for [CustomObject.sharingModel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm#d34589e176): (my emphasis)

> Using API version 29.0 and earlier, this field is read-only and **you can't set this field through Metadata API**; you must use the Salesforce user interface. Using API version 30.0 and later, you can set this field for internal users using the API and the Salesforce user interface.

---

I suspect there may be more going on here than the API allows for. Despite the documentations claims that it will work. I tried to manually change the sharing model for a custom object under the Sharing Settings UI from **Public Read/Write** to **Public Read Only** under     Default Internal Access.

After attempting that I got the message:

> One or more sharing operations has been initiated. See below for additional details. Certain operations may not be available.

And under Test Sharing Rules:

> An organization-wide default update on Tests Update RW has been initiated by Daniel Ballinger on 3/19/2018 4:33 PM. You can't submit any changes for Tests Update RW prior to the completion of the operation. Daniel Ballinger will receive an email when the operation finishes.

An immediate API call to `readMetadata` still showed the old `sharingModel`. Yet after a few minutes (presumably for the batch job to run) it had changed to `Read`.

[Set Your Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sharing.htm&type=5) covers why the change is immediate when increasing the default access but queued when decreasing. Despite that, no change seems to occur based on the Metadata API calls.

---

Sample direct SOAP Metadata API POST to **/services/Soap/m/42.0/00D280000000001**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header>
        <SessionHeader xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <sessionId>00D2800000000001!ARwAQAs_Not_A_Real_Session_ID_EddSwwi2qBSNS.NHZ_wWOrf46RRoNemG2d1eovwiSH8uPp</sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <updateMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <metadata xsi:type="CustomObject">
                <fullName>Test__c</fullName>
                <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
                <label>Test</label>
                <nameField xsi:type="CustomField">
                    <label>Test Record</label>
                    <type>Text</type>
                </nameField>
                <pluralLabel>Tests Update RW</pluralLabel>
                <!-- Changing this has no affect -->
                <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
            </metadata>
        </updateMetadata>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am using API version 39.0.

Comment: @rakeshml OK. Can you share the apex code as part of the question? It will make reproducing it easier.

Comment: Yes! I tried the same and it does not change. Seems that Salesforce is running a background job when we set it to private. I will check after few minutes to verify the same!

Comment: I've tried to bring this up with [Salesforce Docs on twitter for clarification](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/975883419191144448). Will see what comes of it.

Comment: Plan B after twitter didn't work. Implication was that it doesn't work async. I'm not sure that was the underlying issue. Now trying with support case 18656360

Comment: Any luck with the support case @DanielBallinger?

Comment: @DavinCasey most recent update from support this morning "T3 is working on it.
I will follow up with T3 and will keep you posted on updates."

Comment: Great, thanks @DanielBallinger. Looks like we found a proper bug then.

Comment: @DavinCasey New update from support. Still moving up the chain. "Support has logged an investigation with R&D for this issue. R&D is working on this."

Comment: @DavinCasey There is now a known issue for the problem with the CRUD based calls updating the sharingModel

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger, hopefully they get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Hey @DanielBallinger, do you know if the issue was solved? Do you know if there is any link for the known issue article if there is one? I tried it on v42 but I don't see it working, I am wondering if I need to do something else or if it still an issue. Thank you!

Comment: @RogerioHonorio The known issue is at https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=sharingmodel-does-not-update-through-metadata-api-crud-based-calls&Id=a1p3A0000018CP2. It is still showing as *In Review*.